# StackSnippet display parsed HTML entities

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, stack-snippets

If the code block contains [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) then those are parsed and displayed instead of displaying the plain value.

The below code block contains `&#0;` as the input value, but instead of displaying it as such, the parsed text is displayed like �.

```
< !-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    $('body').html($('<input />', {
        id: "myInput",
        type: "text",
        value: "&#0;"
    }));

<!-- end snippet -->
```

becomes:

```js
$('body').html($('<input />', {
    id: "myInput",
    type: "text",
    value: "&#0;"
}));
```

Outside snippet display (and in edit preview) it seems to be fine:

```
$('body').html($('<input />', {
    id: "myInput",
    type: "text",
    value: "&#0;"
}));
```

Source: [Appending a new input textbox DOM to HTML body using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978444)

Comment: How about comments? `&#0;`

Comment: That is caused by the fact that it is a stack-snippet. Without the stack-snippet the entity is showen correctly. A bug indeed. Do notice that if you hit edit, the preview does show the html entity correctly.

Comment: Also note that 'Copy snippet to answer' results in a snippet that with � in the source code rather than `&#0`.

Comment: This is a real bug. Absolutely.

Comment: I've reproduced this locally and am working on a fix now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this bug. I've fixed the issue and HTML entities will display and evaluate properly in the next production build. (meta: > `rev 2014.9.23.2598`, q&a: > `rev 2014.9.23.1885`).